# How to Check Props Type using react-redux useSelector and useDispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-proptypes

Before Introducing react-redux (useSelector,useDispatch) through connect we used to check to props types like this..

```
import PropTypes from 'props-types'     

   Component.propTypes ={
     post:PropTypes.object.isRequired
   }

    const mapStateToProps = state =>({
     post:state.post
    })
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null)(Component);
```

But now react-redux Introduce (useSelector,useDispatch), so using these latest techniques we access state or function like this.

```
import PropTypes from 'props-types' 
import {useDispatch,useSelector}from 'react-redux'
import getLoad from  'function/getLoad'

  const dispatch = useDispatch(()=>getLoad())
  const post = useSelector(state=>state.post)
```

so Now How we Will check Prop Types here Using these techniques.

I tried to check prop types using react-redux (useSelector,useDispatch) like this, kindly check this, is it correct or not kindly response back.

```
   const dispatch = useDispatch( ()=>getLoad() )
   const post = useSelector( state=>state.post )

//checking props types

    Component.propTypes = {
     getLoad:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
     post: PropTypes.object.isRequired
     }
```

Comment: I think it is not possible now. See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296313/proptypes-for-custom-react-hooks#answer-54814692

Comment: There is a big difference here. When you use connect, you wrap your component in a higher order component that sends down the redux-state using props.

When using a hook, ex useSelector, you are fetching the data directly from the store, which means it doesn't come in as a prop. Defining it in prop-types is wrong

Comment: Thank You soo much for Your time. it's means that we don't need to check props type now.

Comment: Well, you absolutely have to check prop types, but only for stuff that is props, not stuff coming from a hook.

Comment: Is there a best practice for checking types now (eg making sure a value isn't `undefined`) besides just checking the type in the component body?