# Why PropTypes failed with Value is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I cannot figure out why prototypes in my function component in React fails with this:

```
`index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `profiles` is marked as required in `Home`, but its value is `undefined`.`
```

The app is working fine and Profiles is defined and I'm using React-redux with hooks and maybe that causing the issue becasue I don't know actually what to do to make the PropTypes to work

My home where this come ups:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Jumbotron, Container, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { ProfileMiddleware } from "../Store/Middleware";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { USERNAME } from "../Services/constAPI";
import Experiences from "../Components/Experiences/Experiences";
import { Spinner } from "../Components/Spinner/Spinner.js";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { profiles, displaySpinner } = useSelector(state => ({
    profiles: state.ProfileReducer.profiles,
    displaySpinner: state.ProfileReducer.displaySpinner
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ProfileMiddleware.getOneProfile(USERNAME));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return !profiles.object ? (
    <>

      <Jumbotron>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
              <Image src={profiles.imageUrl} alt="profile" roundedCircle />
            </Col>
            <Col md={6}>
              <h1>{profiles.firstname + " " + profiles.surname}</h1>
              <h4>{profiles.title}</h4>
              <h5>{profiles.area}</h5>
              <p>{profiles.email}</p>
              <p>{profiles.bio}</p>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Spinner displaySpinner={displaySpinner} />
        </Container>
      </Jumbotron>
      <Experiences />
    </>
  ) : (
    <h3 className="red-text mt-5">The profile is not available</h3>
  );
};

Home.propTypes = {
  profiles: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Home;
```

The reducer as I'm using Redux

```
import { ProfileActions } from "../Actions";

function ProfileReducer(
  state = {
    profiles: {},
    displaySpinner: false
  },
  action
) {
  console.log("data in action", action.data);
  console.log("Action type", action.type);

  switch (action.type) {
    case ProfileActions.GET_ONE_PROFILE:
      return {
        ...state,
        displaySpinner: true
      };
    case ProfileActions.GET_ONE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        profiles: action.data,
        displaySpinner: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default ProfileReducer;
```

I can show else if necessary but the APP works but PropTypes saying profiles are undefined that I cannot understand.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing in any props to `Home`.  Why are you doing that but then trying to require the `profiles` prop?

Comment: I have to check the profiles to be an obj with PropTypes I'm trying to find a solution to make it works. If you know a solution please share an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in any props to `Home`.  If you were, it would look something like

```
const Home = (props) => {
```

Instead, you are getting `profiles` from your redux store.  So simply change

```
Home.propTypes = {
  profiles: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

to

```
Home.propTypes = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

`profiles` is not a prop being passed to `Home`. The proptypes for the `Home` component should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments:

> I have to check the profiles to be an obj with PropTypes I'm trying to find a solution to make it works. If you know a solution please share an answer

If you can guarantee that in your `selector` that's even better, but there're ways to do so in the component.

So let's take a snippet of your code and do that:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { profiles, displaySpinner } = useSelector(state => ({
    profiles: state.ProfileReducer.profiles,
    displaySpinner: state.ProfileReducer.displaySpinner
  }));

  // note Array's and other variable are also objects
  // so we need to do a special check
  const isProfilesAnObject = profiles && profiles.constructor.name === 'Object';
  // created outside of `every` loop, and ternary shortcut to empty array
  const profilesKeys = isProfilesAnObject ? Object.keys(profiles) : [];
  // check that profileKeys is a subset of REQUIRED_KEYS
  // n.b. you need to define this somewhere
  const isProfilesCorrect = REQUIRED_KEYS.every(requiredKey => profileKeys.includes(requiredKey))

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ProfileMiddleware.getOneProfile(USERNAME));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return isProfilesCorrect ?
```

This should work like below:

```js
const checkProfiles = profiles => {
  const REQUIRED_KEYS = ['a', 'b', 'z', 'y']
  const isProfilesAnObject = profiles && profiles.constructor.name === 'Object';
  // created outside of `every` loop, and ternary shortcut to empty array
  const profilesKeys = isProfilesAnObject ? Object.keys(profiles) : [];
  // check that profileKeys is a subset of REQUIRED_KEYS
  // n.b. you need to define this somewhere
  const isProfilesCorrect = REQUIRED_KEYS.every(requiredKey => profilesKeys.includes(requiredKey))
  return isProfilesCorrect;
}
const [profile1, profile2, profile3] = [{
  'a': '10'
}, {
  a: '10', b: '20', z: '260', y: '250'
},{
  a: '10', b: '20', extra_key: 'I\'m being a little bit extra', z: '260', y: '250'
}]

// missing keys
console.log(`profile1 (with keys ${Object.keys(profile1)}) is: ${checkProfiles(profile1) ?'correct': 'incorrect'}`);

// just the right number of keys
console.log(`profile2 (with keys ${Object.keys(profile2)}) is: ${checkProfiles(profile2) ?'correct': 'incorrect'}`);

// doesn't check if there aren't extra keys
console.log(`profile3 (with keys ${Object.keys(profile3)}) is: ${checkProfiles(profile3) ?'correct': 'incorrect'}`);
```

There is also [invariant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/invariant) which you can use for stricter checking. It throws an error if something is false, so you can put exact checking in there, as seen below.

(n.b. ignore the `process` and `module` objects I had to define, and note I'm using `tiny-invariant` for convenience )

```js
const checkProfiles = profiles => {
  const REQUIRED_KEYS = ['a', 'b', 'z', 'y']
  const isProfilesAnObject = profiles && profiles.constructor.name === 'Object';
  // created outside of `every` loop, and ternary shortcut to empty array
  const profilesKeys = isProfilesAnObject ? Object.keys(profiles) : [];
  // check that profileKeys is a subset of REQUIRED_KEYS
  // n.b. you need to define this somewhere
  const isProfilesCorrect = REQUIRED_KEYS.every(requiredKey => profilesKeys.includes(requiredKey))
  // really need to make sure 'z' exists and is a string
  invariant(typeof profiles.z === 'string', `Profiles is expected to have a key 'z' that is a string, but found ${JSON.stringify(profiles.z)}`)
  return isProfilesCorrect;
}


console.log(checkProfiles({
  a: 10,
  z: 'valid'
}))
try {
  checkProfiles({
    a: 10,
    z: 20
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

```html
<script>
  var process = {
    env: 'production'
  }
  var module = {
    exports: {}
  }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tiny-invariant@1.2.0/dist/tiny-invariant.cjs.min.js">
</script>
```

Either of those should work depending on how seriously you need to make sure your variables exist and are correct

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you didn't pass `props`, pay attention to:

```
const Home = () => {
```

You should write `const Home = props => {` or destruct the `props` in the beginning of your function component, like below:

```
const Home = ({ profiles }) => {
```

And then use it inside your execution context of the function component. Also, you can put the default value for your props like below:

```
const Home = ({ profiles = 'something' }) => {
```

The `'something'` is a sample, it can be everything, or write like below at the end of your function component declaration:

```
Home.defaultProps = {
  profiles: 'something'
};
```

I hope it helps you, but surely you should read the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) a little bit more.

Comment: I read the documentation can you point to an example with function component as those examples are with class component and a bit different. Also second thing if I define props or profiles like that into the function itself what I have to do as I getting an error as that is never read. Can I have a full example about it please will help a lot

Comment: However standing to this i cannot do it as react doesn't allow it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814692/7882685

Comment: The user isn't using props for profile, so telling them how to do so is sort of moot.